# How to Make Subdomain Checker Like WordPress.com Has?

Tags: php, wordpress, subdomain

I'm giving free subdomain for my reader, most of them use it for blogspot custom domain CNAME record.

I want to know how to create subdomain checker like wordpress.com has? So i can easily spot whether the subdomain already taken, so they can check on their own if it's available or not. I'm using PHP on my site. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP function `checkdnsrr()` ( https://www.php.net/checkdnsrr ). Look for `A` record.

Comment: Check the doc. Just fill in your subdomain in first input parameter, then 'A' in 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 0):

A subdomain is going to be linked to your control panel such as cPanel or Plesk. Which one do you have?

Comment: You need to look up a script to hook into the cPanel API to do this then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use catch-all for this purpose-

1. Point your DNS (must have catch-all option) to the same domain
2. Make sure your webhost supports catch-all

For DNS, you may use a service like Zonomi. For host, you may use a service like PHPFog.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you asked for. Sorry!

Comment: i'm manually create subdomain on cpanel. but i need a subdomain checker tool so my reader can check on their own.